# How to handle Firebase push notification when iOS app is suspended/killed and user clicks on the notification?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, push-notification

I want to know what function should be called back or when I receive a notification while my app is suspended/killed. I am able to handle while my APP is in foreground/background however when the app is killed that's where I am not sure how and where to handle or parse my notification payload?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On open application from the notification, you will get the notification data in application:didFinishedLaunchingWithOptions method will called.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    if (launchOptions != nil)
    {
        // opened from a push notification when the app is closed
        NSDictionary* userInfo = [launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey];
        if (userInfo != nil)
        {
             NSLog(@"userInfo->%@", [userInfo objectForKey:@"aps"]);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        // opened app without a push notification.
    }
}
```

Swift 5.1

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey : Any]? = nil) -> Bool {
    if launchOptions != nil {
        // opened from a push notification when the app is closed
        let userInfo = launchOptions?[.remoteNotification] as? [AnyHashable : Any]
        if userInfo != nil {
            if let object = userInfo?["aps"] {
                print("userInfo->\(object)")
            }
        }
    } else {
        // opened app without a push notification.
    }
}
```

Comment: How about in Swift?

Comment: now I need to Present and a Viewcontroller from appdelegate. How can I achieve that?

Comment: You can use the ApplicationDelegate.window.rootviewcontroller to present viewcontroller

Answer (score 0):

You can handle push notification when app is killed, use below method in your `SceneDelegate`

```
  func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {       
    guard let _ = (scene as? UIWindowScene) else { return }
    if let notificationResponse = connectionOptions.notificationResponse {
         // get data from notification 
         let data = notificationResponse.notification.request.content.userInfo
         // get specific key from that data
         guard let feature = data["feature"] else {
             return
         }
     }      
}
```